# Allow Arbitrary Loads in iOS

Tags: ios, app-store

`Allow Arbitrary Loads`  to `YES` 
[image]

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

In my project, I'm Used HTTP Protocol to call the API.

Is accept or reject in App store app review process.

Comment: will accept .Is there any pblm

Comment: will accept , NSAllowsArbitraryLoads is not a good practice , if you need whitelist some URL

Comment: This may not be a problem for app review team, please share rejection message from the team, and what type of application you're submitted for review (like, financial app).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, They will accept it in Appstore review.. i have used it in my live ios application.